# postMessage is not working with dynamically added iframe in firefox addon using xul

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, firefox-addon-sdk, xul

I am creating a firefox addon using xul. I have added a dynamic iframe using following script:

```
//addon script:
let chromeUrl = 'https://myserver/downloadProduct.html';
                        Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');//Services
                        let activeWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');

                        let mainDocument = activeWindow.document;

                        let iframeEl;
                        iframeEl = mainDocument.createElement('iframe');

                        iframeEl.id = "d";
                        iframeEl.setAttribute('src',chromeUrl);
                        iframeEl.setAttribute("tooltip", "aHTMLTooltip");
                        iframeEl.setAttribute("autocompleteenabled", true);
                        iframeEl.setAttribute("autocompletepopup", "PopupAutoComplete");
                        iframeEl.setAttribute("disablehistory",true);
                        iframeEl.setAttribute('type', 'content');
                        iframeEl.setAttribute('height', '32px');


                        window.document.documentElement.insertBefore(iframeEl, window.document.documentElement.window);
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage,false);
```

Above script is successfully adding a new iframe on page. Now I want to receive messages from iframe to my addon. I have created a postMessage event in iframe script, script as follows:

```
//iFrame Script:
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Download").click(function () {
                parent.postMessage({ Action: "DOWNLOADED", Result: null }, "*");
            })

            $("#NotNow").click(function () {
                parent.postMessage({ Action: "NOT_NOW", Result: null }, "*");
            })

            $("#Never").click(function () {
                parent.postMessage({ Action: "DO_NOT_SHOW", Result: null }, "*");
            })
        });
    </script>
```

But I am not able to receive message in my firefox addon.

Can anybody help?

Comment: We're going to need to know what `window` is in your first code block (i.e. you did `var window = ??what??;`) and `parent` in your second code block.

Comment: Just FYI: It is quite unlikely that you will get you add-on approved for distribution on AMO if you are using an HTML file that is not supplied with your add-on (i.e. one that is from a web based source) for part of your user interface.

Comment: Please provide your HTML file (or at least one that has your buttons) so we have the code necessary to test this (i.e. a [mcve]).

Comment: Also, please provide your `receiveMessage` function.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
window.document.getElementById("iframeId").contentWindow.document.getElementById("elementId").addEventListener('click', function() {
                                //Do something
                            }, false);
```

This script can be added just after adding dynamic iframe on the page.